IoT head cover with mounted wireless camera
Serval people embed themselves in serval jobs, work, house chores, etc.
All of this has a great potential to

teach and learn

make others embed themselves and put them into a position to acquire, and tall into, using stuff, as examples, into teaching and learning

people want to make Android smatphone videos, video games, and console video games where you can project the game onto a television, or console, and interact with a joy stick (and there may be various versions of joy sticks or input mechanisms).


In order, to have access, to this series of activities, people need the following appareil:
An IoT (internet of things) head cover with mounted wireless camera mounted in position of the forehead.
The users can then review, the scenes, partitioning them into software-usable and reasoning aiding chunks, by connecting their computer or smatphone to the IoT camera (which, may also have a memory of it's own, or might just embed the videos onto the computer or smatphone memory via WiFi, using software to support this).
I was thinking it would be best to have a hood that was made of something like a scuba diving suit foam, and the equipment was, waterproof, and the hood was a little bit like those head apparels that can be envisioned on the heads of Lego person characters.
Thank you for your cooperation.
Where can I find such appareil, and such related software, and what is the related software?
